# Uploading image in Mysql database

Tags: php

I have the following code.All the values are inserted into database other than the imaage field.In the database it is "image" in the image filed> whats wrong with the code?? waiting for ur reply,thank u.

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Upload error";
} else {
    echo $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "images/".$_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "319");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("ju", $con);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO teacher (tchr_name,tchr_degree,tchr_desig,tchr_email,tchr_phone,tchr_interest,image)
    VALUES
        ('$_POST[tchr_name]', '$_POST[tchr_degree]', '$_POST[tchr_desig]', '$_POST[tchr_email]', '$_POST[tchr_phone]', '$_POST[tchr_interest]', '$_FILES[image][name]')
    ";

    if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
        die('Error: '.mysql_error());
    }
}
//echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: take look another answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535717/uploading-and-moving-image-files-on-web-server-image-not-uploaded/47366018#47366018

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that the image has been uploaded ok? Check the error field $_FILES['image']['error'] to make sure there were no errors when uploading. Or try doing a print_r of the $_FILES array to see if it has all the information.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for your reply.I have just solved the problem. :)But the new problem is how i can retrieve a particular image from my database? I can use the userid or password as a key of the people of whom i wanna print the image?I have to solve the problem within today :((

Comment: you should use the field that identifies the person. Maybe the email?